# Javascript Repeating Audio

Tags: javascript, html, loops, audio, repeat

I have been trying to get this JavaScript to repeat the audio once it has finished, I have had a look around and I am inexperienced with JavaScript, although I have made attempts tweaking and researching I have had no luck so far.

I would be very grateful for any help and tips

Many thanks- Grant

```
<!-- Script inside body -->

    <!-- Audio Player -->
        <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
        var audioElement = document.createElement('audio');
        audioElement.setAttribute('src', 'music/audio.mp3');
        audioElement.setAttribute('play', 'autoplay');
        //audioElement.load()
        $.get();
        audioElement.addEventListener("load", function() {
        audioElement.play();
        audioElement.loop();
        }, true);


        $('.play').click(function() {
        audioElement.play();
        });


        $('.pause').click(function() {
        audioElement.pause();
        });

    });
        </script>

       <div class="play">Play</div>
       <div class="pause">Stop</div>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Set loop property for repeat track:

```
audioElement.loop = true
```

Comment: Thank you @Mihail!

Answer (score 2):

Some browser doesn't support the loop propperty/attribute to audio. In this, you can add event listener instead like:

```
var myAudio = document.createElement('audio');
myAudio.setAttribute('src', 'test.mp3');
myAudio.play()
myAudio.addEventListener('ended', function() {
    this.currentTime = 0;
    this.play();
}, false);
```