# Looping audio onclick with Javascript

Tags: javascript, loops, audio, onclick

I am creating a launchpad for an assignment, and struggled to find a way to loop and audio clip on click, and then stop the audio when clicked again. I have this code but it doesn't loop atm (I'm new to Javascript so it may need explaining to me).

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
        <head>
            <meta charset="utf-8">
            <title>Title</title>
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
            <script> var one = new Audio(); var two = new Audio(); var three = new Audio(); var four = new Audio();
            var five = new Audio(); var six = new Audio(); var seven = new Audio(); var eight = new Audio();
            one.src = "files/audio/one.wav"; two.src = "files/audio/two.wav"; three.src = "files/audio/three.wav";
            four.src = "files/audio/four.wav"; five.src = "files/audio/five.wav"; six.src = "files/audio/six.wav";
            seven.src = "files/audio/seven.wav"; eight.src = "files/audio/eight.wav";
            </script>
        </head>


<div class="parent">
        <div class="item" onmousedown="one.play()">Bass</div>
        <div class="item" onmousedown="two.play()">Bass</div>
        <div class="item" onmousedown="three.play()">Bass</div>
        <div class="item" onmousedown="four.play()">Beat</div>
        <div class="item" onmousedown="five.play()">Beat</div>
        <div class="item" onmousedown="six.play()">Beat</div>
        <div class="item" onmousedown="seven.play()">Drum</div>
        <div class="item" onmousedown="eight.play()">Drum</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As shown on other SO posts, the Web Audio element has a loop property you can set to true
[Loop audio with JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13610638/loop-audio-with-javascript) and [Javascript Repeating Audio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17890319/javascript-repeating-audio)

for each of your instances of Audio, you will need to set it to true.
e.g.

```
one.loop = true;
two.loop = true;
```